# Refreshing listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

i already posted my question and i hope i will get an answer this time, i'm trying to refresh my listbox by using variables foreach elment in the listbox but i got only the new element and the other items deleted her's my code:

```
private void refresh()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "http";

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

    request.Method = Method.GET;
    request.AddParameter("action", "atms");

    request.AddParameter("lang", "ar");
    request.AddParameter("mode", "xml");
    request.AddParameter("appli", "WP");
    request.AddParameter("city_id", selectedState._id);
    client.ExecuteAsync(request, ParseFeedCallBack_ListAgence);
}

public void ParseFeedCallBack_ListAgence(IRestResponse response)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        ParseXMLFeedAgences(response.Content);
    }
}

private void ParseXMLFeedAgences(string feed)
{
    if (feed == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        XElement xmlItems = XElement.Parse(feed);
        XDocument xmlItems2 = XDocument.Parse(feed);
        ResultSearch_List.ItemsSource =
            from response in xmlItems.Descendants("result")
            let add = response.Element("Address")
            let idagence = response.Element("id")
            let latt = response.Element("Latitude")
            let longt = response.Element("Longitude")

            select new State
            {
                Address = add == null ? null : add.Value,
                _idagence = idagence == null ? null : idagence.Value,
                Latitude = latt == null ? null : latt.Value,
                Longitude = longt == null ? null : longt.Value,
            };

        foreach (var resp in xmlItems2.Descendants("result"))
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = "http:";

            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.GET;
            request.AddParameter("action", "atms_distances");
            request.AddParameter("lang", "ar");
            request.AddParameter("mobile_latitude", "35.843283");
            request.AddParameter("mobile_longitude", "10.61617");
            request.AddParameter("atm_latitude", "35.2579090");
            request.AddParameter("atm_longitude", "10.7992144");

            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    ParseXMLFeedDistance(response.Content);
                });
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
    }
}

private void ParseXMLFeedDistance(string feed)
{
    if (feed == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        XDocument xmlItems2 = XDocument.Parse(feed);

        var list = new List<State>();

        foreach (XElement val in xmlItems2.Descendants("result").Last().Elements())
        {
            list.Add(new State
                {
                    TotalDistance = val.Value,
                });
        }

        ResultSearch_List.ItemsSource = list;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

her's my code and please tell me what should i change:

```
foreach (XElement val in xmlItems2.Descendants("result"))
            {


                states.Add(new State
                {
                    Address = val.Element("Address").Value,
                    _idagence = val.Element("CityId").Value,
                    Latitude = val.Element("Latitude").Value,
                    Longitude = val.Element("Longitude").Value,

                });
            }

            foreach (var resp in xmlItems2.Descendants("result"))
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient();
                client.BaseUrl = "http://";

                RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

                request.Method = Method.GET;
                request.AddParameter("action", "atms_distances");

                request.AddParameter("mode", "xml");
                request.AddParameter("appli", "WP");
                request.AddParameter("mobile_latitude", "35.843283");
                request.AddParameter("mobile_longitude", "10.61617");
                request.AddParameter("atm_latitude", "35.2579090");
                request.AddParameter("atm_longitude", "10.7992144");

                client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {

                    XDocument xmlItems22 = XDocument.Parse(response.Content);


                    foreach (XElement val in xmlItems22.Descendants("result").Last().Elements())
                    {

                        //  distance = val.Value;
                        states.Add(new State
                        {
                            TotalDistance = val.Value,
                        });
                    }
                    ResultSearch_List.ItemsSource = states;
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `List` as your data source, instead use `ObservableCollection`:

```
// keep this in your class
ObservableCollection<State> States { get; set; }

// add to constructor
States = new ObservableCollection<State>();
```

Now change the last function (`ParseXMLFeedDistance`) to this:

```
private void ParseXMLFeedDistance(string feed)
{
    if (feed == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        XDocument xmlItems2 = XDocument.Parse(feed);

        foreach (XElement val in xmlItems2.Descendants("result").Last().Elements())
        {
            // distance = val.Value;
            list.Add(new State
            {
                TotalDistance = val.Value,
            });
        }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Don't reset the list, you are always destroying it and creating from scratch.

Comment: this solution deleted the old elments and i got the new ones !

Comment: I don't understand, did it help or not?

Comment: no, can you tell me what should i do with the first list because the first elements have been deleted and i see only the new ones.thx

Comment: Have you replaced the `List<>` with the `ObservableCollection<>`? Also, put a breakpoint whenever you call `new ObservableCollection<>`, at that moment you are creating a *new* list.

Comment: i did the samething with the first load of the listbox using ObservableCollection<> but the problem that he creates for me another list ccontaining new elements just after the first one !

Comment: You are the one who is creating a new element when you write `new`. Please review your code and check when you **create** a new list.

Comment: i postet my code bellow please tell me what i'm doing wrong !

Comment: Where did you create `states`? Can you run it with debugger and inspect it when you are adding items to it? Do you know how to debug?

Comment: i declared it before the call of the constructor of the phoneapplicationPage, in the second call of add items it increments the new elements and the size of the observablecollection increments also and it creates then another list under the old one with new elements

Comment: What do you mean "creates then another list", it is hard to decipher your exact problem. Please post full source code